# If exists (select top 1 1) with multiple instructions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that checks for the existence of a record in a table and if it exists, updates the record, else, inserts a new record.

```
@myFieldID int = NULL,
@newTitle varchar(50) = NULL

    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1
    FROM table
    WHERE myField = @myFieldID)

    UPDATE table1
    SET title = @newTitle
    WHERE myFieldID = @myFieldID

    UPDATE table2
    SET newTitle = @newTitle
    WHERE myFieldID = @myFieldID

    ELSE 

    INSERT INTO table1
    (
    title
    )
    SELECT @newTitle
```

The problem is, when I have the second UPDATE, I get an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'"

How do I update 2 tables within the same conditional "IF"?  Or, do I simply have to test for the existence of the same record twice?

Comment: Wrap your update statements in a BEGIN/END block.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but it is worth noting that `EXISTS` is smart enough to just ignore anything in the `SELECT` clause and to stop at the first match, so it is customary to just use `SELECT *`, rather than complicating it with TOP or similar things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is you're trying to multiple updates in a single IF statement with no BEGIN/END. Change your if statement to

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1
FROM table
WHERE myField = @myFieldID)
BEGIN
     UPDATE table1
     SET title = @newTitle
     WHERE myFieldID = @myFieldID

     UPDATE table2
     SET newTitle = @newTitle
     WHERE myFieldID = @myFieldID
END
ELSE
```